# C# Start and stop Apache

Tags: c#, apache, process

I need to start and stop apache process from a C# application (without prompt window).
Mind that I'm not speaking of the apache service, but just the console application.

I tried to open it with

```
 string cmd = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(CMD_APACHE);
 prs_apache = new Process();
 prs_apache.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 prs_apache.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 prs_apache.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 prs_apache.StartInfo.FileName = cmd;
 prs_apache.Start();
```

I tried sending CTRL-C command and also with process.close or process.closemainwindow() but no one works.
Is there any other way to control Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds like you're actually asking how to hide the window (it looks like you've got the restart command already firing).  Let me know if that's incorrect:

```
prs_apache.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Comment: I need to stop apache without killing his process. I saw that I can use CloseMainWindow() method only if apache has his window visible. With "prs_apache.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;" the window still remains...